# How to keep elements visible after the first scroll in React-visibility-sensor?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a react-circular-progress bar that animates till 90 upon visible, but stops once it's visible. I have tried various solutions, but they didn't seem to work. The method which I am trying now (using react hooks) seems to be promising but lands me a 'State is not defined error'

```
const percentage = 90;

function Stat(){
 [State ,setState] = useState({visible: false });

const onChangeVisibility = isActive => {
    setState({ ...State, visible: isActive });
}
    return (
        <StatsContainer>      
             <Stats>
            <VisibilitySensor onChange={e => onChangeVisibility(e)} active={!State.visible}>
            {({ isVisible }) => {
              const percentage = isVisible ? 90 : 0;
              return (
              <CircularProgressbar value={percentage} text={`${percentage}%`} />         
            );
            }}
          </VisibilitySensor>
              </Stats>
       </StatsContainer>
    )
}
export default Stat
```